# android - XMLPullParser Error

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

i have a xml file (local ) that stored in : /assets

I'm using XMLpulparser to parse that xml but in my LogCat i have these problem's  :

[image]

here is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<countries>
<country>
    <name>Iran</name>
    <phonecode>+98</phonecode>
    <code>IRI</code>
</country>
<country">
    <name>United State</name>
    <phonecode>+1</phonecode>
    <code>USA</code>
</country>
```

Comment: are you using a dtd or anything similar validation?

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you that error because there is a " sign on the second country start tag. Also seems to be missing a countries closing tag at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

one of your country's tag contains " symbol, which is not acceptable in xml tag names.

You wrote

```
    <country">
    ....
    </country>
```

you must write

```
    <country>

    </country>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *# While you have some errors in you XML code, which you may check from above answers, the ideal way to parse your XML code will be something
>   like*

**Ex. XML file content (saved in external storage as `code.xml`)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<countries>
<country>
 <name>Iran</name>
 <phonecode>+98</phonecode>
 <code>IRI</code>
</country>
<country>
 <name>United State</name>
 <phonecode>+1</phonecode>
 <code>USA</code>
</country>
</countries>
```

> *# Lets begin parsing it*

**1. First create a Helper class**

```
package in.example.helpers;

import android.util.Xml;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class XmlDataParseHelper {

private XmlPullParser parser;
private static final String NULL = null;

/**
 * 
 * @param in
 * @throws XmlPullParserException
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 */
public XmlDataParseHelper(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException,
        IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
    try {
        parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @return XmlPullParser
 */
public XmlPullParser getParser() {
    return parser;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param parser
 * @param tag
 * @return String
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws XmlPullParserException
 */
public static String readTag(XmlPullParser parser, String tag)
        throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String tagData = "";
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, NULL, tag);
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        tagData = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, NULL, tag);
    return tagData;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param parser
 * @param tag
 * @param attributeName
 * @return String
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws XmlPullParserException
 */
public static String readAttribute(XmlPullParser parser, String tag,
        String attributeName) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, NULL, tag);
    String attributeData = parser.getAttributeValue(NULL, attributeName);
    parser.nextTag();
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, NULL, tag);
    return attributeData;
}

}
```

**2. Read the xml file as**

```
public InputStream readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException,
            IOException {
    //check external storage present
    // else throw new IOException();

    return new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/" + fileName);
}
```

**3. Pass the InputStream to another method which initializes the XMLPullParser object**

```
public void readXmlFile(String fileName) {
     try {
        if (fileName.isEmpty())
        throw new NullPointerException();
        readData(new XmlDataParseHelper(readFile(fileName)).getParser());
     } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

**4. Atlast parse the XMLPullParser object as**

```
public void readData(XmlPullParser parser)
                throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    String tagName = "";
    Log.w("Developer", "Reading file...");
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT :
                Log.w("Developer", "Reading backup file...");
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG :
                tagName = parser.getName();
                if (tagName.equals("countries")) {
                    Log.w("XMLParse", "Start TAG countries");
                    // do something when countries tag starts
                }
                if (tagName.equals("country")) {
                    Log.w("XMLParse", "Start TAG country");
                    // do some when country tag starts
                } else if (tagName.equals("name")) {
                    // read tag value using XmlDataParseHelper class
                    String countryName = XmlDataParseHelper.readTag(parser,
                                    "name");
                    Log.w("XmlParser", "Country name : "+countryName);
                } else if (tagName.equals("phonecode")) {
                    String countryPhoneCode = 
                                  XmlDataParseHelper.readTag(parser,"phonecode");
                    Log.w("XmlParser", "Country Phone code : "+countryPhoneCode);
                } else if (tagName.equals("code")) {
                    String countryCode = 
                                 XmlDataParseHelper.readTag(parser, "code");
                    Log.w("XmlParser", "Country code name : "+countryCode); 
                }
            break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG :
                tagName = parser.getName();
                if (tagName.equals("countries")) {
                      // do something when counties tag is close.
                }           
            break;
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }
    Log.w("Developer", "File parsing complete...");
 }
```

To read a file just call the method `readXmlFile(String fileName)` in an `AsyncTask` with the name of file stored in the External Storage.

*`#I hope it helps you and others in the future.`*

The whole android working example code is here https://gist.github.com/rachitrm/7810837 or fork the project http://www.github.com/rachitrm/rm-xmlparser/

Comment: Thank you for answering , all things are ok but i think your _**"XmlDataParseHelper"**_ is not right , because when it want to read tag  it throws an exception and it can't read a tag content (data) . would you please correct it and edit your post ? Thank you very much !

Comment: @kianm98 well i am using the helper class in my app, it works good :) hope some problem in logic some where.

Comment: @kianm98 i have the answer 0 errors now with project source enjoy.

Comment: Thank you your code on GitHub worked ok but I should copy the file into ExtrenalDirectory of phone , but i want my file be a private file and i want to read my xml file that stored in : '/assets' or '/res/xml/' what can i do for this?

Comment: Thank you your code on GitHub worked ok but I should copy the file into ExtrenalDirectory of phone , but i want my file be a private file and i want to read my xml file that stored in : '/assets' or '/res/xml/' what can i do for this?

Comment: Thank you your code on GitHub worked ok but I should copy the file into ExtrenalDirectory of phone , but i want my file be a private file and i want to read my xml file that stored in : '/assets' or '/res/xml/' what can i do for this? @twntee

Comment: @kianm98 change the directory path, append the `filepath` in this line `return new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            +YOUR_FILE_PATH+ "/" + fileName)`;